# Unable to open serial port in linux

Tags: c++, linux

using fedora 11,

In serial class:

```
/*
     \return 1 success 

\return -1 device not found

\return -2 error while opening the device

\return -3 error while getting port parameters

 \return -4 Speed (Bauds) not recognized

\return -5 error while writing port parameters

\return -6 error while writing timeout parameters

*/
`char serialib::Open(const char *Device,const unsigned int Bauds){`

    struct termios options; // Structure with the device's options
    // Open device
    fd = open(Device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);            // Open port
    if (fd == -1) return -2;                        // If the device is not open, return -1
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);                    // Open the device in nonblocking mode
```

......................

```
[termina]$ dmesg | grep tty

console [tty0] enabled

serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A

serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A

00:07: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A

00:08: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
```

.......................................................

in my main program i do a Ret=LS.Open(DEVICE_PORT,4800);
and Ret value is -2 which means error while opening the device as stated above
could it be a permission problem? how can i resolve this and open the port, thanks!

Comment: "could be"? You mean you didn't bother checking `errno`?

Comment: that is what im wondering, not the error shown there

Comment: When `open` returns `-1`, instead of just returning, add a line to print the actual error. This can be done with the [`perror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror) function. If you don't understand the error message, then edit your question to include it.

Comment: Are you running as root?

Answer (score 1):

> could it be a permission problem

It's very likely. Depending on what linux you are using there are several options for changing permissions.

It may be as simple as adding the current user to the dailout group. Or you may need to change the udev rules to set the permissions for the serial port.

Comment: Or (to test) he can temporarily allow "others" full access to serial port.